# Why the benchmark result of netty FastThreadLocal not faster much than ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, netty

I use the benchmark which in the netty project io.netty.microbench.concurrent.FastThreadLocalFastPathBenchmark。

When I run it directly, the result of beachmark show that FastThreadLocal faster much than ThreadLocal.

However, when I just change the method get() to the set(),  the result of beachmark show that FastThreadLocal not faster much than ThreadLocal.

This is the result:

```
Benchmark                                            Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
FastThreadLocalFastPathBenchmark.fastThreadLocal    thrpt   20  1233.992 ± 101.533  ops/s
FastThreadLocalFastPathBenchmark.jdkThreadLocalGet  thrpt   20  1203.562 ±  77.841  ops/s
```

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 The Netty Project
 *
 * The Netty Project licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
 * version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
package io.netty.microbench.concurrent;

import io.netty.microbench.util.AbstractMicrobenchmark;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Threads;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class benchmarks the fast path of FastThreadLocal and the JDK ThreadLocal.
 */
@Threads(4)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, batchSize = 100)
public class FastThreadLocalFastPathBenchmark extends AbstractMicrobenchmark {

    private static final Random rand = new Random();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static final ThreadLocal<Integer>[] jdkThreadLocals = new ThreadLocal[128];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static final FastThreadLocal<Integer>[] fastThreadLocals = new FastThreadLocal[jdkThreadLocals.length];

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < jdkThreadLocals.length; i ++) {
            final int num = rand.nextInt();
            jdkThreadLocals[i] = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
                @Override
                protected Integer initialValue() {
                    return num;
                }
            };
            fastThreadLocals[i] = new FastThreadLocal<Integer>() {
                @Override
                protected Integer initialValue() {
                    return num;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int jdkThreadLocalGet() {
        int result = 0;
        for (ThreadLocal<Integer> i: jdkThreadLocals) {
            i.set(rand.nextInt());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int fastThreadLocal() {
        int result = 0;
        for (FastThreadLocal<Integer> i: fastThreadLocals) {
            i.set(rand.nextInt());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

get() result:

```
Benchmark                                            Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
FastThreadLocalFastPathBenchmark.fastThreadLocal    thrpt   20  51634.074 ± 6936.996  ops/s
FastThreadLocalFastPathBenchmark.jdkThreadLocalGet  thrpt   20  53212.778 ±  660.392  ops/s
```

Comment: I think there is no conflict. Because the fastthreadLocal is thread independence.

Comment: So are you saying when you run the benchmark you get expected results, but when you modify the benchmark to use `set()` instead of `get()` you get different results?

Answer (score 0):

Well `FastThreadLocal` is optimised for `get` and not for `set` so what you see is not surprising in general.

Comment: FastThreadLocal use array instead of map,  normally, not only get() but also set() should be faster than ThreadLocal. Why do you say FastThreadLocal is optimised for get and not for set?